# Blender Script not working

Tags: python, blender

I want to make a Side Scroller in Blender with python. Could someone please explain to me why this script is not working?

```
import bge

def main():

    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    player = cont.owner

    scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()

    keyboard = bge.logic.keyboard

    if bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.DKEY]:
        player.localPosition.x += 0.1

    elif bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.AKEY]:
        player.localPosition.x += -0.1

    elif bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.WKEY]:
        player.localPosition.z += 0.5

main()
```

Comment: Can you post the traceback? It would be helpful

Comment: Please fix your indentation as in python this is part of the program's semantics and as such could be already part of your issues

Comment: the weird thing is, there is no traceback. everything it says is "python script fail, look in the console for now"

Comment: For blender specific scripting you will find more help at [blender.stackexchange.com](http://blender.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score -1):

Going by the script working for me and the error you say you get, it would appear that you are using the script the wrong way. The bge module is only available when the game engine is running and it sounds like you are trying to run it as a normal blender script by clicking the run script button in blender's text editor.

To use a python script within blender's game engine you need to add logic bricks to the player object with your script assigned to a python controller that has a sensor attached to it, as your script reads straight from the keyboard, you can add an always sensor with pulse enabled.

[image: sample logic bricks]

Comment: I tried it this way two days ago and it didn't  work. But now it worked for some reason. Thanks